# SQL INSERT - FROM 1 Table to another database with aggregate (conditional)

Tags: sql-insert, insert-into

Hi i try to search with no luck.
I need help to Insert a set of records (rows) into another database.
both database has the same exact column name and exact datatype.

something like this:
    Insert Into A from B
    Where A.columnID <> B.columnID
        AND B.column3 = ' NO'

my code:

```
INSERT INTO [HOOA].[dbo].[tblPatientInfo]
SELECT * FROM [MainClinic].[dbo].[tblPatientInfo]
WHERE [HOOA].[dbo].[tblPatientInfo].AccountID <> [MainClinic].[dbo].tblPatientInfo].AccountID
AND
[HOOA].[dbo].[tblPatientInfo].GlobalData = 'NO'

--I TRY THIS AS WELL but no luck
INSERT INTO [HOOA].[dbo].[tblPatientInfo]
SELECT * FROM [MainClinic].[dbo].[tblPatientInfo]
WHERE GlobalData = 'NO'
AND [HOOA].[dbo].[tblPatientInfo].AccountID <> MainClinic].dbo].tblPatientInfo].AccountID
```

Answer (score 0):

I Assume your Db is Mysql.

Firstly, Is both databases are present in same server & single user????

If So, Is Access privileges for accessing the databases is set???

For all these questions, u can refer this 'http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/grant.html#grant-table-privileges'.
 It provides u all required things for assigning privileges based on columns & Tablewise too.

Regards,
VPK

Comment: yes both databases are in the same server and sa user.
thanks for the checkin

Comment: its an SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 0):

Then try something like this, It could work if u had assigned privileges correctly for both users.

INSERT INTO [HOOA].[dbo].[tblPatientInfo]
(SELECT * FROM [MainClinic].[dbo].[tblPatientInfo]
WHERE [MainClinic].[dbo].[tblPatientInfo].AccountID <> (select AccountID from [HOOA].[dbo].[tblPatientInfo])
AND
(select GlobalData from [HOOA].[dbo].[tblPatientInfo]) = 'NO')

The Reason is in your select statement u haven't selected the database Hooa only, but u have used those in where clause.

Comment: thanks for the reply.
hmm..but i got an error msg

Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
Incorrect syntax near ')'.